# Check command line arguments is not char c++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to check command line argument is either alphabets or number

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argv[1] is not int) //How does it check if it is number or alphabets
    { 
        cerr<< "arguments must be integer" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

if i run in linux terminal output would be like

```
./a.out aasmsnsak
arguments must be integer
```

Comment: Easiest thing to do is pass the argument into `strtol` or `std::stoi` and see if the argument can be parsed into an integer.

Comment: Use std::isalpha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this with standard library is with `strtol` from `<cstdlib>`. Another one uses `istringstream`.

```
char *endptr;
const long int argument = strtol (argv[1], &endptr, 10);  // <cstdlib>
if(endptr[0] != '\0') {
    cerr << "arguments must be integer" << endl;
    return -1;
} else if (argument == LONG_MIN || argument == LONG_MAX) {  // <climits>
    // Alternatively you can check for ERANGE in errno
    cerr << "arguments value is out of range" << endl;
    return -1;
} else {
    /* Right type of argument received */
    [..]
}
```

**[Demo using strtol](https://www.ideone.com/yPV7KR)**

```
istringstream iss(argv[1]);
int argument;
char more;
if(iss >> argument) {
    if(iss >> more) {
        cerr << p << ": arguments must be integer" << endl;
        return -1;
    } else {
        /* Right type of argument received */
        [..]
    }
} else {
    cerr << p << ": arguments must be integer" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

**[Demo using istringstream](https://www.ideone.com/y0fATW)**

Comment: things came out in my mind using try and catch do you think it's better? like using <stdexcept> ??

Comment: In your strtol what is '\0' means?

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan `'\0'` is the character code for a null character. Strings in C must be terminated with a null; otherwise the common string manipulation routines do not know when to stop processing. In the case of `strtol`, it stops parsing when it finds anything that cannot possibly be a number. This could be the null terminator or it could be anything else that isn't a digit. `strtol` sets `endptr` to point at the character that stopped the parsing. If it points at the null terminator, the whole string was read. If it points at anything else the whole string was not an integer.

Comment: @user4581301 what about the strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10); what does the constant 10 means??  in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/  say it is a base, what does it changes?

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan `10` is the radix or base of the number. You can set `10` for decimal, `2` for binary, `16` for hex etc. If you use value `0`, it means auto deduce the base from string. For example if string starts with a `0`, the number is parsed as octal, beginning with `0x` are parsed as hex and numbers beginning with non-zero digits are parsed as decimal.

Answer (score 1):

At very first, the command line arguments might exist of multiple characters. So you will have to iterate over all of them:

```
for(char* arg = argv[1]; *arg; ++arg)
```

Now I assume that you want to classify a string containing *any* non-digit character as being non-number, so inside the loop, you would check each character for digits:

```
if(!isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*arg)))
{
    // non-number-string!

    break; // no need to go on...
}
```

Another variant could be just trying to cast to number:

```
std::istringstream s(argv[1]);
int n;
s >> n;
if(s) // number read?
{
    char c;
    s >> c;
    if(!s.eof())
    {
        // not last character reached!
        // -> no number
    }
}
```

Or:

```
char* end;
long number = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
//                              ^ needed for detecting, if end of string reached
if(*end || errno == ERANGE)
{
    // doesn't point to terminating null character -> no number
    // or number read was out of range
}
```

C-style variant:

```
int n, int l;
if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d%n", &n, &l) == 1 && argv[1][l] == 0)
{
    // successfully scanned an integer and end of string reached -> is a number
}
```

Comment: NIce thanks,  i have editted my quesition to ( argv[1] is not digit) but still answer my question.